Connect Portenta H7 with module CAT M1 with AWS
I need some help. I'm trying to connect my Portenta H7 to AWS using the Portenta CAT M1 NB-IoT module with MQTT and AT commands.
I found that the AT^SBNW command should work for this, but I haven't been able to find examples, so I'm unsure how the command works.
I have tried using AT^SBNW=is_cert,1, and the module responded with "SECURE CMD READY: SEND COMMAND...". Then, I tried sending the secure command to the module, as described in this guide (https://ptelectronics.ru/wp-content/uploads/organizatsiya_bezopasnogo_ssl-soedineniya.pdf) (Section 6.2). However, the response was: SECURE CMD SERVICE TIMEOUT ERROR
Can anyone provide guidance or examples? Maybe someone has been in my position before. Thanks!

Asking for "guidance" is too vague and asking for examples are off topic for Stack Overflow. You need to show what you've tried and explain how it failed then we may be able to help.

I have tried using AT^SBNW=is_cert,1, and the module responded with "SECURE CMD READY: SEND COMMAND...".
Then, I tried sending the secure command to the module, as described in this guide (https://ptelectronics.ru/wp-content/uploads/organizatsiya_bezopasnogo_ssl-soedineniya.pdf) (Section 6.2).
However, the response was:
SECURE CMD SERVICE TIMEOUT ERROR
I’m asking for guidance because I’ve tried many things, and maybe someone has been in my position before. Thanks for your response!

Please edit the question to add details, rather than trying to add them in comments.

Thanks. Its my first time in stackoverflow.
